# Issue with Parsing JSON Data in Python what to do

Tags: python, windows

I am encountering an issue while trying to parse JSON data in Python using the `json` module. I've retrieved the data from an API, and when I attempt to parse it using `json.loads()`, I get an error.

error Messages: The error message I'm receiving is:

*json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)*

Attempts: I've tried modifying the JSON data format, ensuring that it complies with the JSON specification. However, I still encounter the same error.

Expected vs Actual Behavior: I expected the JSON data to be successfully parsed into a Python dictionary, but instead, I'm getting a `JSONDecodeError`.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you are having trouble with. Also include the full error traceback.

Comment: Additionally, please include the string you're trying to parse which causes the error